# Sharepoint: how to attach file to flow approval email?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a list with data of clients like company name,address, phone number, etc. and I have to make contract based on these data, and then send it in an approval email. If I attach each contract individually to the corresponding row how can I attach my contract file to the email in the flow maker? 
also can I make so that before sending the email, the flow will create the contract automatically based on the data from the list?

Comment: you should try on [SharePoint Stackexchange dedicated site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no out of the box solution for emailing attachment files. The SPUtility class does not include any method for attaching files.

I wrote [this solution](https://github.com/jyarbro/SPEmailAttachmentWorkflow) for attaching list item attachments and documents to emails. Unfortunately it's a farm solution as it uses server side object model code rather than client side object model code.

I see you've marked your post as SharePoint Online, meaning your best bet is a provider hosted solution in which you hook a custom workflow activity to a trusted server you own to handle the CSOM code.